# Powershell - convert XML to CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I was able to convert XML to CSV by using the following code:

```
    #read from file
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "c:\pstest\test.xml"
#export xml as csv
$inputFile.Transaction.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "c:\pstest\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

It works if the files contain only one root node with one type of child nodes, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction>
    <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515552017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
    </TXNDETAIL>
    <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515622017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
    </TXNDETAIL>
    <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515972017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
    </TXNDETAIL>
</Transaction>
```

The output would be like:

```
    "RecordID";"SequenceNumber";"TransactionType";"ActionCode";"TransactionID";"SellerCode";"BuyerCode";"TransactionReference";"TransactionDescription1";"TransactionDescription2";"DocumentType";"DocumentNumber";"DocumentDate";"DocumentAmount";"CurrencyCode";"TransactionAmount";"TransactionDueDate";"AdditionalInformation1";"AdditionalInformation2";"HashCode"
"02";"1";"01";"01";"17500515552017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
"02";"2";"01";"01";"17500515622017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
"02";"3";"01";"01";"17500515972017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
```

Which is great.

However, the input file in reality has a "header line"  information, the TXNHEAD tag

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction>
    <TXNHEAD>
        <RecordID>01</RecordID>
        <FileName>001</FileName>
        <IntermediaryCode>19000033</IntermediaryCode>
        <ActualizationDate>20170314</ActualizationDate>
        <SequenceNumber>001</SequenceNumber>
        <NumberofRecords>3</NumberofRecords>
        <AmountofRecords>30000</AmountofRecords>
    </TXNHEAD>
    <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515552017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
    </TXNDETAIL>
    <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515622017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
    </TXNDETAIL>
    <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515972017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
    </TXNDETAIL>
</Transaction>
```

When applying the same code, I get:

```
    "RecordID";"FileName";"IntermediaryCode";"ActualizationDate";"SequenceNumber";"NumberofRecords";"AmountofRecords"
"01";"001";"19000033";"20170314";"001";"3";"30000"
"02";;;;"1";;
"02";;;;"2";;
"02";;;;"3";;
```

When I am trying this code instead to retrieve just the head:

```
#read from file
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "c:\pstest\test.xml"
#export xml as csv
$inputFile.Transaction.TXNHEAD.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "c:\pstest\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

I get:

```
"#text"
"01"
"001"
"19000033"
"20170314"
"001"
"3"
"30000"
```

What I am trying to achieve, is this output:

```
"RecordID";"FileName";"IntermediaryCode";"ActualizationDate";"SequenceNumber";"NumberofRecords";"AmountofRecords"
"01";"001";"19000033";"20170314";"001";"3";"30000"
"RecordID";"SequenceNumber";"TransactionType";"ActionCode";"TransactionID";"SellerCode";"BuyerCode";"TransactionReference";"TransactionDescription1";"TransactionDescription2";"DocumentType";"DocumentNumber";"DocumentDate";"DocumentAmount";"CurrencyCode";"TransactionAmount";"TransactionDueDate";"AdditionalInformation1";"AdditionalInformation2";"HashCode"
"02";"1";"01";"01";"17500515552017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
"02";"2";"01";"01";"17500515622017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
"02";"3";"01";"01";"17500515972017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first object (or `Select-Object` etc.) in a pipeline defines the header for output no matter if it's file or console output.

What you could do is convert them to csv in two rounds and add it to the same file. Ex:

```
$inputFile.Transaction.TXNHEAD | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Set-Content -Path "c:\pstest\test.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$inputFile.Transaction.TXNDETAIL | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" | Add-Content -Path "c:\pstest\test.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

You can also combine them like this:

```
$inputFile.Transaction.TXNHEAD, $x.Transaction.TXNDETAIL |
ForEach-Object { $_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" } |
Set-Content -Path "c:\pstest\test.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Since he wants type information to be present in CSV, better not include the `NoTypeInformation` flag.

Comment: He doesn't. Read again

Comment: Hmm. He said: "I desire the following output:" and output contains type information row, starting from `RecordID`. Please check last code block in the question.

Comment: Then please add your answer, because as far as I can see you are making up quotes and details. He wants the values from his header (`TXNHEAD`-node). TypeInformation from `Export-CSV` is something completely else. My answer generates the desired output

Answer (score 2):

Here's my Code for this:

```
# ============================================================================= 
#  
# NAME:xml2csv.ps1
#  
# AUTHOR: 
# THANKS TO: Rick Sheeley (original snippet on STack Overflow) 
# DATE  : 
#  
# COMMENT:  
# Send large XML with multiple children and Attributes to CSv for analysis
#
# Note: For versions 3.0 or newer only
# ============================================================================= 

function Get-Attributes([Object]$pnode)
{

    if($pnode.HasAttributes) {

        foreach($attr in $pnode.Attributes) {

            $xattString+= $attr.Name + ":" + $attr."#text" + ","

        }

    }

    else {

            $xattString = $pnode.nNode + ": No Attributes,"

    }

    return $xattString
}

function Get-XmlNode([ xml ]$XmlDocument, [string]$NodePath, [string]$NamespaceURI = "", [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.')
{
    # If a Namespace URI was not given, use the Xml document's default namespace.
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) { $NamespaceURI = $XmlDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI }   

    # In order for SelectSingleNode() to actually work, we need to use the fully qualified node path along with an Xml Namespace Manager, so set them up.
    $xmlNsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($XmlDocument.NameTable)
    $xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
    $fullyQualifiedNodePath = "/ns:$($NodePath.Replace($($NodeSeparatorCharacter), '/ns:'))"

    # Try and get the node, then return it. Returns $null if the node was not found.
    $node = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode($fullyQualifiedNodePath, $xmlNsManager)
    return $node
}

cls
$fin = "<Filepath>\<myFile>.xml"
$fout = "<Filepath>\<myFile>.csv"

Remove-Item $fout -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

[xml]$xmlContent = get-content $fin
$row=0
$COMMA=","
$pNode = "ROOT"

# Replace all "MyTopNode" with your top node...

$nNode = "MyTopNode"

$xmlArray  = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Row= $row;Parent=$pNode;Node=$nNode;Attribute='';ItemType='Root';Value=''})

$xmlArray[$row].Row = $row
$xmlArray[$row].Parent = $pNode
$xmlArray[$row].Node = $nNode
$xmlArray[$row].Attribute = ""
$xmlArray[$row].ItemType = "Root"
$xmlArray[$row].Value = $attr."#text"
$row++

if($xmlContent.MyTopNode.HasAttributes) {

    foreach($attr in $xmlContent.MyTopNode.Attributes) {

        $xmlArray += @(
            [pscustomobject]@{Row= $row;Parent=$pNode;Node=$nNode;Attribute='';ItemType='Root';Value=''})

        $xmlArray[$row].Row = $row
        $xmlArray[$row].Parent = $pNode
        $xmlArray[$row].Node = $nNode
        $xmlArray[$row].Attribute = $attr.LocalName
        $xmlArray[$row].ItemType = "Attribute"
        $xmlArray[$row].Value = $attr."#text"
        $row++

    }

}

# Begin TRY

try {

    foreach($node in $xmlContent.MyTopNode.ChildNodes) {

        $pNode = "MyTopNode"

        $nNode = $node.LocalName

        $xmlArray += @(
            [pscustomobject]@{Row= $row;Parent=$pNode;Node=$nNode;Attribute='';ItemType='Root';Value=''})

        $xmlArray[$row].Row = $row
        $xmlArray[$row].Parent = $pNode
        $xmlArray[$row].Node = $nNode
        $xmlArray[$row].Attribute = ""
        $xmlArray[$row].ItemType = "Root"
        $xmlArray[$row].Value = $attr."#text"
        $row++

        if($nNode.HasAttributes) {

            foreach($attr in $node.Attributes) {

                $xmlArray += @(
                    [pscustomobject]@{Row= $row;Parent=$pNode;Node=$nNode;Attribute='';ItemType='Root';Value=''})

                $xmlArray[$row].Row = $row
                $xmlArray[$row].Parent = $pNode
                $xmlArray[$row].Node = $nNode
                $xmlArray[$row].Attribute = $attr.LocalName
                $xmlArray[$row].ItemType = "Attribute"
                $xmlArray[$row].Value = $attr."#text"
                $row++

            }

        }

        foreach($sNode in $node.ChildNodes) {

            $pNode = $nNode
            $snNode = $sNode.LocalName

            $xmlArray += @(
                [pscustomobject]@{Row= $row;Parent=$pNode;Node=$nNode;Attribute='';ItemType='Root';Value=''})

            $xmlArray[$row].Row = $row
            $xmlArray[$row].Parent = $pNode
            $xmlArray[$row].Node = $snNode
            $xmlArray[$row].Attribute = ""
            $xmlArray[$row].ItemType = "Root"
            $xmlArray[$row].Value = $attr."#text"
            $row++

            if($sNode.HasAttributes) {

                foreach($attr in $sNode.Attributes) {

                    $xmlArray += @(
                        [pscustomobject]@{Row= $row;Parent=$pNode;Node=$nNode;Attribute='';ItemType='Root';Value=''})

                    $xmlArray[$row].Row = $row
                    $xmlArray[$row].Parent = $pNode
                    $xmlArray[$row].Node = $snNode
                    $xmlArray[$row].Attribute = $attr.LocalName
                    $xmlArray[$row].ItemType = "Attribute"
                    $xmlArray[$row].Value = $attr."#text"
                    $row++

                }

            }
        }
    }

    $xmlArray | SELECT Row,Parent,Node,Attribute,ItemType,Value | Export-CSV $fout -NoTypeInformation
}

# End TRY

# Begin Catch

Catch [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException]
{
    $ErrException = Format-ErrMsg -errmsg $_.Exception
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $ErrorID = $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber

    Write-Host                           "  "
    Write-Host                           "  "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta  ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta      "==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!=="
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta  ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan     "Details:"  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White        "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan         "`t  Module:        $modname"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan         "`t Section:        $sFunc"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan         "`t On Line:        $line"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan         "`t File:           $fSearchFile | Search will be skipped!!"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White        "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan      "Exception Message:"  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White       "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow       "`t ShortMessage:   $ErrorMessage"       
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow       "`t ErrorID:        $ErrorID"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White        "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta      "$ErrException"  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White        "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta  "========================================================================================================================================== "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow       "This File will be added to the Skip list. Please restart script $sScriptName ...." 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta  "========================================================================================================================================== "
    Write-Host                           "  "
    Write-Host                           "  "
}

Catch
{
    $ErrException = Format-ErrMsg -errmsg $_.Exception
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $ErrorID = $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber

    Write-Host                           "  "
    Write-Host                           "  "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkRed  "================================================================================================================================================="
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red      "==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!==!!Error!!=="
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkRed  "================================================================================================================================================="
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "Details:"  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan     "`t  Module:        $modname"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan     "`t Section:        $sFunc"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan     "`t On Line:        $line"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan     "`t File:           $fSearchFile"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "Exception Message:"  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow      "`t ShortMessage:   $ErrorMessage"       
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta  "`t ErrorID:        $ErrorID"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red      "$ErrException"  
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "

# Show etended error info if in debug mode.

    if ($extDebug -eq $true) {

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red      "Extended Debugging info"  

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
        $error[0].Exception | Format-List * -Force
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor White    "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "

    }

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkRed  "==================================================================================================================================================== "
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkRed  "==================================================================================================================================================== "
    Write-Host                           "  "
    Write-Host                           "  "

    Break

# End Catch

}

# Begin Finally

Finally
{
    "finis."
    Exit 0

# End Finally

}
```