# Powershell convert batch of xml to csv

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I only need Powershell for this task and only have experience with coding in Stata - help appreciated.

I have a large number of xml files where each one is a single record from a survey, so it has variable names and responses for one person.

I need to convert those files to a csv file. From reading other posts I understand that I need to loop over the files, but I don't know how to tell Powershell that I want the survey data to be exported, rather than file attributes.

I've tried something like this:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\fs59\Desktop\temp\* -Include *.xml
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $xml = [XML](Get-Content $item) 
    $xml | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\fs59\Desktop\temp\myoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
}
```

This runs without an error but the output does not contain the survey data.

UPDATE: Hi, I have managed to send the results to csv but the output is one long column. Is there a way of having the output in several rows, one per each xml file?

```
# Get all XML files
$items = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\* -Include *.xml

# Loop over them and append them to the document
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $inputFile = [XML](Get-Content $item) #load xml document    

#export xml as csv
$inputFile.TT_client_survey_2018_v1.ChildNodes | Export-Csv -Path    C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\myoutput12.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - convert XML to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393961/powershell-convert-xml-to-csv)

Comment: How many levels of XML

Comment: What does your xml look like? What is in the output?

Comment: Hi @ArcSet, 3 levels of xml.