# PowerShell - convert XML with common header and items to CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I want to convert XML to CSV using PowerShell.
I've been loooking at this example: [Powershell - convert XML to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393961/powershell-convert-xml-to-csv), which is a good step of the way, but my XML structure and need is slightly different.
My XML looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction>
   <FileName>001</FileName>
   <IntermediaryCode>19000033</IntermediaryCode>
   <ActualizationDate>20170314</ActualizationDate>
   <SequenceNumber>001</SequenceNumber>
   <NumberofRecords>3</NumberofRecords>
   <AmountofRecords>30000</AmountofRecords>
   <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515552017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
   </TXNDETAIL>
   <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515622017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
   </TXNDETAIL>
   <TXNDETAIL>
        <RecordID>02</RecordID>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionType>01</TransactionType>
        <ActionCode>01</ActionCode>
        <TransactionID>17500515972017001</TransactionID>
        <SellerCode>2200919TRY</SellerCode>
        <BuyerCode>KOCZER</BuyerCode>
        <TransactionReference> </TransactionReference>
        <TransactionDescription1> </TransactionDescription1>
        <TransactionDescription2> </TransactionDescription2>
        <DocumentType>01</DocumentType>
        <DocumentNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentDate>20170301</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentAmount>10000</DocumentAmount>
        <CurrencyCode>949</CurrencyCode>
        <TransactionAmount>10000</TransactionAmount>
        <TransactionDueDate>20170505</TransactionDueDate>
        <AdditionalInformation1> </AdditionalInformation1>
        <AdditionalInformation2> </AdditionalInformation2>
        <HashCode>XXXXXXXX</HashCode>
   </TXNDETAIL>
</Transaction>
```

I want to place the FileName to AmountofRecords values in front of each TXNDETAIL:

```
"FileName";"IntermediaryCode";"ActualizationDate";"SequenceNumber";"NumberofRecords";"AmountofRecords";"RecordID";"SequenceNumber";"TransactionType";"ActionCode";"TransactionID";"SellerCode";"BuyerCode";"TransactionReference";"TransactionDescription1";"TransactionDescription2";"DocumentType";"DocumentNumber";"DocumentDate";"DocumentAmount";"CurrencyCode";"TransactionAmount";"TransactionDueDate";"AdditionalInformation1";"AdditionalInformation2";"HashCode"
"001";"19000033";"20170314";"001";"3";"30000";"02";"1";"01";"01";"17500515552017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
"001";"19000033";"20170314";"001";"3";"30000";"02";"2";"01";"01";"17500515622017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
"001";"19000033";"20170314";"001";"3";"30000";"02";"3";"01";"01";"17500515972017001";"2200919TRY";"KOCZER";"";"";"";"01";"XXXXXXXXXXX";"20170301";"10000";"949";"10000";"20170505";"";"";"XXXXXXXX"
```

By using this code, I get the TXNDETAIL, but not the header information:

```
$Input = $args[0]
$Output = $args[1]

#read from file
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content $input
#export xml as csv
$inputFile.Transaction.TXNDETAIL | Export-Csv $Output -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

How do I add the header information to each line?

Comment: A true CSV shouldn't have two header columns with the same name. How would you want to handle `SequenceNumber` in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that, unlike the previous question your refer to, in this case your header information is in a different part of the xml. To capture that, you will have to use xpath:

So, for example, try:

```
$headers = $inputfile.SelectNodes("//TXNDETAIL[1]/preceding-sibling::*") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

In this case, `echo $headers` outputs:

```
FileName
IntermediaryCode
ActualizationDate
SequenceNumber
NumberofRecords
AmountofRecords
```

which is your required header information. You can use it to export to csv, etc.