# Powershell convert xml to csv

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

i have to convert my xml file to a csv file.
I really do not have a clue how to do it. I've read many posts but I just don't get it ...

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<license_usage xmlns="http://www.example.com/report">
    <start_time timestamp="1643670000">2022-01-31T23:00:00+00:00</start_time>
    <end_time timestamp="1645615967">2022-02-23T11:32:47+00:00</end_time>
    <group_by>hour</group_by>
    <license_time_intervals>
            <license_time_interval timestamp="1643670000" datetime="2022-01-31T23:00:00+00:00">
                                                                <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="login">0</license_count>
                                    <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="extended_contact">0</license_count>
                
                <license_count license_type="support_full">0</license_count>
                                                        
        </license_time_interval>
            <license_time_interval timestamp="1643673600" datetime="2022-02-01T00:00:00+00:00">
                                                                <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="login">2</license_count>
                                    <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="extended_contact">0</license_count>
                
                <license_count license_type="support_full">2</license_count>
                                                        
        </license_time_interval>
            <license_time_interval timestamp="1643677200" datetime="2022-02-01T01:00:00+00:00">
                                                                <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="login">0</license_count>
                                    <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="extended_contact">0</license_count>
                
                <license_count license_type="support_full">0</license_count>
                                                        
        </license_time_interval>
            <license_time_interval timestamp="1643680800" datetime="2022-02-01T02:00:00+00:00">
                                                                <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="login">0</license_count>
                                    <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="extended_contact">0</license_count>
                
                <license_count license_type="support_full">0</license_count>
                                                        
        </license_time_interval>
            <license_time_interval timestamp="1643684400" datetime="2022-02-01T03:00:00+00:00">
                                                                <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="login">0</license_count>
                                    <license_count license_type="support_full" reason="extended_contact">0</license_count>
                
                <license_count license_type="support_full">0</license_count>

        </license_time_interval>
    
    </license_time_intervals>
</license_usage>
```

And I want to convert it with Powershell to a csv that looks like this:

```
license_count/0/_license_type,license_count/0/_reason,license_count/0/__text,license_count/1/_license_type,license_count/1/_reason,license_count/1/__text,license_count/2/_license_type,license_count/2/__text,_timestamp,_datetime
support_full,login,0,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,0,1643670000,2022-01-31T23:00:00+00:00
support_full,login,2,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,2,1643673600,2022-02-01T00:00:00+00:00
support_full,login,0,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,0,1643677200,2022-02-01T01:00:00+00:00
support_full,login,0,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,0,1643680800,2022-02-01T02:00:00+00:00
support_full,login,0,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,0,1643684400,2022-02-01T03:00:00+00:00
support_full,login,0,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,0,1643688000,2022-02-01T04:00:00+00:00
support_full,login,3,support_full,extended_contact,0,support_full,3,1643691600,2022-02-01T05:00:00+00:00
and so on
```

so I call the xmlFile:

```
$xmlFile = Get-Content "C:\temp\example.xml"
```

How to go on?

Can you pleeease help me?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393961/powershell-convert-xml-to-csv

Comment: It is difficult to find answers because your requested data scheme is not typical. Are you open to a different interpretation of the how the CSV will be structured?

Comment: Thank you! But I have read that and still can't solve my problem... could you please help me?

Comment: @AdminOfThings - Yes, of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different interpretation of the data:

```sh
# return XmlDocument type from xml content
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\temp\example.xml")

# drill down to the license time intervals
$xml.license_usage.license_time_intervals.license_time_interval | Foreach-Object {
    # current license time interval object
    $interval = $_
    # iterate license_count nodes
    # use calculated properties to mix higher level properties with nested properties
    # license count comes from the node text
    $_.license_count | Select @{n='timestamp';e={$interval.timestamp}},
        @{n='datetime';e={$interval.datetime}},
        license_type,reason,
        @{n='license_count';e={$_.'#text'}}
} | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

---

The output CSV will contain headers `timestamp,datetime,license_type,reason,license_count`. Note that this will result in multiple lines that contain the same `timestamp` and `datetime` values because they have multiple associated `license_count` nodes. Personally, this is easier for me to read and sort in PowerShell and CSV. Scaling wide with the properties could require the code to be more dynamic since you may not always know how many `license_count` nodes there will be. This code should work regardless of the number of nodes as long as the schema remains the same.

Comment: One more question: How could I filter that only columns are shown that have "login" as an entry for the column heading "reason"?

Comment: Change the last line to `} | Where reason -eq 'login' | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType`